# How can I overcome the openssL error and digital envelope routines when running react application using react-scripts start?

Tags: node.js, openssl, conv-neural-network

when I run the command: npm run start on the cmd I get the following error:

C:\Users\princ\Documents\code\Plant_Disease_Detection\Frontend>npm run start

```
> photo@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\princ\Documents\code\Plant_Disease_Detection\Frontend\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports 
}

Node.js v20.5.1
```

I've tried updating node.js and installing OpenssL but none of that seems to work. Please help.

Comment: This has been asked more than a hundred times and answered over and over and over again; just do the most basic and obvious possible search by putting `[nodejs] error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported` in the search box.